# What is equivalent code segment/command of the matlab's release() in python?

Tags: python, matlab

I would like to perform same operation in python for the following line written in Matlab:

[release()](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/releasesystemobject.html?searchHighlight=release&s_tid=srchtitle)

```
invoke(material, 'Transparency', '0');
invoke(material, 'Create');
release(material);
```

The material element is defined, but I did not want to write this case because it is unimportant.

What will be the equivalent code segment/line in python?

Answer (score 0):

It seems likely that it is the `del` (delete) statement in python that you are looking for

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-del-statement

Comment: The function in the message you wrote has been very useful for me, thank you

Comment: @KaanKIVIRCIK Excellent. Feel free to upvote or select this as an accepted answer.